# Read Committed Data when in transaction in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to capture record history wherein i pass the old and new data to a php function and it returns an array of changed values.

So, is there a way to get the previous committed data from DB using same session before committing the current transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
...
COMMIT;
```

Plan B:

See if you can use a `TRIGGER`, which has access to the old and new values as the pseudo tables `OLD` and `NEW`.

(If you would like to discuss your goal more; we might be able to provide a more focused Answer.)